# How can i use htaccess for query string?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Is there any way to rewrite unknown parameters with unknown values ?
The unknown parameters and values are appended to url.

```
ex: http://localhost/index.php?c=25&unknown-parameter=unknown-value&unknown-parameter=unknown-value&unknown-parameter=unknown-value
```

to something like this

```
ex: http://localhost/25/?p/?/?p/?/?p/?
```

Or more clearly

```
http://localhost/25/unknown-parameter/unknown-value/unknown-parameter/unknown-value..etc
```

Comment: Who generating these unknown parameters?

Comment: Also what is `/?p/` in URL?

Comment: question mark is for `GET` params. You shouldn't use it in order to replace the occurences of `unknown-parameter`. You might just want to remove them

Comment: Unknown parameters are generated by $_GET[parameter]